# Преобразование строки в массив чисел по одному символу(строку в массив символов, а их в массив чисел)

Tags: java, массивы, циклы

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String test = "1" ;
       int[] testInt = new int[1];
       
   for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++){
       testInt[i] = test.charAt(i);
       System.out.println(testInt[i]);
   }
}
}
```

отчего на выходе 49?
совсем не понимаю

Answer (score 1):

Потому что символ `1` имеет код `0x31 = 49` (десятеричное).
Вы использовали именно код символа.

Полагаю, что хотелось перевести его в число 1. Для этого в данном случае (одна цифра) можно просто из кода цифры вычесть код символа `0`, его значение `(int)'0'=0x30=48`

```
testInt[i] = (int)test.charAt(i) - (int)'0';
```

В общем же случае для строк `Integer.parseInt() или Integer.valueOf()`

Answer (score -1):

```
String buf= "09876543210"; 
List l=  Arrays.asList(buf.split("{1}"));
List resu = l.stream().map(n->Integer.parseInt((String) n)).toList();
System.out.println(resu.toString());
```

Comment: нетипизированные списки и Stream API с кастингом в map??

Comment: да,  не вижу проблемы.   int[] result= Stream.of(buf.split("{1}")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();